# Which function to use to transform a pandas DataSeries?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform a pandas DataSeries and I'm unsure what the best solution is.

For example: I have a table like this:

```
Pseudo-id|Time  |Name|Key  |Attr  |Value | Unit
1        |10:00 |A   |Value|height|10    | mm
2        |10:00 |A   |Value|width |20    | mm    
1        |11:00 |B   |Value|height|10    | mm
3        |11:00 |B   |Value|depth |20    | mm
```

I want to get the resulting (sparse) table, like the following below (text and image version :-) ).

```
Time |Name|Key1 |Attr1 |Value1|Unit1|Key2 |Attr2|Value2|Unit2|Key3 |Attr3|Value3|Unit3
10:00|A   |Value|height|10    |mm   |Value|width|20    |mm   |-    |-    |-     |-
11:00|B   |Value|height|10    |mm   |-    |-    |-     |-    |Value|depth|20    |mm
```

[image]

The resulting columns should be a combination of the column value of "Pseudo-Id" and the respective column which is pivoted. I have to avoid hierarchical headers.

What is the best way of doing this?
I thought about the pivot function. But I don't have an option for specifing how the column names are created.
I could create new column names after pivoting. But the problem could be to identify which column is present for a row, because not all rows contain all columns. I could solve this problem with a map I create beforehand.

Are there any other functions which I may don't know? Maybe there is a more elegant way :-)

Comment: Seems like `unstack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `unstack` with `fill_value`

```
s=df.set_index(['Time','Name','id']).unstack(fill_value='').sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
s
Out[88]: 
            Key1 Attr1 Value1 unit1   Key2 Attr2 Value2 unit2   Key3 Attr3  \
Time Name                                                                    
10   A     value     h     10    mm  value     w     20    mm                
11   B     value     h     10    mm                            value     d   
          Value3 unit3  
Time Name               
10   A                  
11   B        20    mm
```

---

Data input

```
df
Out[89]: 
   id  Time Name    Key Attr  Value unit
0   1    10    A  value    h     10   mm
1   2    10    A  value    w     20   mm
2   1    11    B  value    h     10   mm
3   3    11    B  value    d     20   mm
```